# Не правильно отображается кодировка при чтении файла

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Есть программа на electron js которая читает содержимое файла с помощью node js. При чтении файла с русским текстом выдает "кракозябры".
Без electron все работает.

Версия electron: 9.1.0
Node.js: 12.18.2
OS: Windows 10

Заранее благодарю.

index.js

```
function openFileClick() {
  let path = dialog.showOpenDialogSync({ properties: ["openFile"] });
  if (path == undefined) {
    return;
  }
  fileContent = fs.readFile(path[0], {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, fileContent) {
    if (err) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(fileContent.toString())
  });
  
}
```

test.txt

```
Привет мир
```

Вывод:

```
╨Я╤А╨╕╨▓╨╡╤В ╨╝╨╕╤А
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что файл именно в кодировке UTF-8? Вы сами сохраняли его в этой кодировке?

Comment: @vsemizhetbyt Да

Comment: А если исключить electron, в обычном нодовском скрипте та же проблема проявлятся?

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Без electron работает.

Comment: Тогда вам, наверное, стоит уточнить, куда вы выводите текст, который кракозябрами: в консоль, в GUI Electron, ещё куда-то. Может, добавить чуть больше кода для контекста.